# Spring Batch throwing NullPointerException while saving data in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I tried implementing Spring batch. Here I'm trying to save data from text file to save in database. I'm getting NPE while processing.

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

@Value("${inputFile}") 
private Resource resource;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public JobConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
    this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
}

@Bean
public Job job() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB-Load")
            .start(fileReadingStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step fileReadingStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("File-Read-Step1")
            .<Student,Student>chunk(5)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .processor(new Processer())
            .writer(new Writer())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Student> itemReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Student> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    flatFileItemReader.setResource(resource);
    flatFileItemReader.setName("File-Reader");
    flatFileItemReader.setStrict(false);
    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(LineMapper());
    return flatFileItemReader;
}

@Bean
public LineMapper<Student> LineMapper() {
    DefaultLineMapper<Student> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Student>();
    FixedLengthTokenizer fixedLengthTokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    fixedLengthTokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "name"});
    fixedLengthTokenizer.setColumns(new Range[] { new Range(1, 5)});
    fixedLengthTokenizer.setStrict(false);

    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(fixedLengthTokenizer);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new DefaultFieldSetMapper());

    return defaultLineMapper;
}

}
```

Writer Class

```
@Component
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<Student> {

@Autowired
private StudentRepo repo;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends Student> items) throws Exception {
    for(Student s:items) {
        System.out.println(s.getName());
    }
    try {
    repo.saveAll(items);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

here I'm used JPARepository to save my text file data into database in my custom writer class. Here **StudentRepo** is null.

Why it's null ?
I tried another method method used same **StudentRepo** to store in db manually there is no issue.
Only in writer class it's null.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your spring configuration. More details needed.

Comment: I created one controller and saved the data by using same repository , Not getting any error. Only inside ItemWriter getting NPE. I debugged I got null in repo.

Comment: How are you getting the instance of `Writer` where `Writer.writer()` is being called?

Answer (score 1):

In `fileReadingStep`, you do not use the `Writer` bean that gets created through the `@Component` annotation. You create a new `Writer` instance which the Spring context is unaware of wherefore the repo field is not set and remains `null`.

You need to inject the `Writer` bean like you inject the `ResourceLoader` or the `JobBuilderFactory` and then use the bean in `fileReadingStep`.